# Formulario para activar o desactivar un usuario con checkbox

Tags: laravel

Quiero controlar cuando creo o modifico un usuario con un checkbox activarlo o desactivarlo pero no se queda guardado en la base de datos.

Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'login',
    'email',
    'password',
    'activated',
];
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $user= new User();

    //Si existe el usuario mandar alerta
    // Sino guardar los datos
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string','unique:event'],
        'login' => ['required', 'string','unique:event'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string','unique:event'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string']
    ],
    // Errores personalizados
    [
        'name.unique' => 'Nombre de Usuario duplicado',
        'login.unique' => 'Nombre de Login duplicado',
        'email.unique' => 'Nombre de Email duplicado',

    ]);

        $user-> name= $request->name;
        $user-> login= $request->login;
        $user-> email= $request->email;
        $user-> password=  Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->activated = $request->activated ;

        $user->save();



    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Vista

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="activated" name="activated">
<label class="form-check-label" for="activated">
      Activado
</label>
```

Pero por algún motivo no se queda guardo, como 0 o 1

se supone que en la base de dato se guarda como 0 == false o  como 1 == true

pero en el checkbox creo que es donde esta el fallo, creo que de alguna forma que no sé debería de controlarlo, lo que no se es como lo recoge el dato el checkbox

creo que en el checkbox habría qie poner value="1"

en store controlar sino es 1 guardar como 0

y como debería de hacerlo en update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el checbox no está marcado como `checked`, no va a estar presente en el request. [Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#additional_attributes):

> Note: Unlike other input controls, a checkbox's value is only included in the submitted data if the checkbox is currently `checked`. If it is, then the value of the checkbox's `value` attribute is reported as the input's value, or `on` if no `value` is set.

Entonces una de las posibilidades es dejar el input en el formulario tal cual lo tenes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="activated">
```

Y en el controlador comprobar si el campo está presente y asignarle valor `1` a la propiedad de tu modelo, o `0` si no está presente

```
$user->activated = $request->has('activated') ? 1 : 0;
```

Pero esto puede dar lugar a confusión, ya que otro programador podría pensar que si envía el campo `activated` con valor `0`, sería también válido.

---

Para mí lo mejor sería que el backend valide ese campo como un boolean requerido, y sea el frontend el que se adapte para enviar siempre es campo.
Por ejemplo:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    //...
    'activated' => ['required', 'boolean']
],
[
    //...
]);
//...
$user->activated = $request->activated;
```

Y en el front, por ejemplo, poner un input oculto con el valor `0` por defecto, y en el caso que el usuario marque el checkbox, que el valor del checkbox pise el valor del input anterior con el valor `1`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="activated" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="activated" value="1">
```

Para el caso de un formulario de edición de un registro existente, le agregas un condicional para imprimirle el atributo checked al checkbox (ejemplo si estas usando blade templates):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="activated" value="1" @if($user->activated) checked @endif >
```

Comment: @AlejandroManuelCarrion no había visto que también preguntabas por el caso de un update. Ahí lo agregué a la respuesta